# Pass the data from Component to Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to get the query parameter from the URL in to a component and it works as expected and now I want to get the data from this component in to another. But I am getting `undefined`.

Component where I am trying to get the query parameter:

```
export class ProjectShipmentComponent implements OnInit {
  public repProjectNumber : string;

  constructor( private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

   ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.repProjectNumber = params['reportProject'];
      console.log(this.repProjectNumber);
    })}
  getPrjNum()
  {
    return this.repProjectNumber;
  }}
```

Now I am trying to retrieve this `repProjectNumber` in to another component like below

```
    import { ProjectShipmentComponent } from '../project-shipment.component';
    export class ReportingFilterComponent implements OnInit {
    repPrj : string;
    constructor(private psc :ProjectShipmentComponent ) {
       this.repPrj = this.psc.getPrjNum();
      console.log(this.repPrj);
```

I get undefined here. Is there any order in which the `ngOnInit` is executed? Because while debugging I didn't see `ngOnInit` executed when the `getPrjNum` function call is made from `ReportingFilterComponent`. How can I get this working?

Comment: Use an observable for `repProjectNumber`.

Comment: Read [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) and you will find what you are seeking.

Comment: You can use : ViewChild Directive, you can use a service with an observable where you put the data and retrieve it in a component, you can use Input directives. There are many way of doing it, it depends of your structure and your needs

Answer (score 0):

Passing data between components doesn't work like this because every time you create instance of Component, it's data is re initiated. Try using a service. Example:

First Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    {{message}}
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

}
```

Second Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from "../data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  template: `
    {{message}}
    <button (click)="newMessage()">New Message</button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentMessage.subscribe(message => this.message = message)
  }

  newMessage() {
    this.data.changeMessage("Hello from Sibling")
  }

}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private messageSource = new BehaviorSubject('default message');
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(message: string) {
    this.messageSource.next(message)
  }

}
```

Example from https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: I tried using service inbetween but shows me the same issue `undefined`

Comment: Share the code of service too

Comment: I've added a sample too.

Comment: Here I am getting the data in the component, as I am getting it from the URL

Comment: Add your service code in your question so that I can get a complete picture.